# WPF 4 ContentPresenter TextWrapping style is not applied to implicitedly generated TextBlock

Tags: wpf, styles, contentpresenter

If I assign a piece of text to the `Content` property of a `ContentPresenter`, a `TextBlock` control is generated by the `ContentPresenter` at render time to contain that text.

If I create a style that applies to`TextBlock` properties and assign it to that `ContentPresenter`, the does not appear to apply to the implicitly generated `TextBlock`s.

```
<Style x:Key="SampleStyle">
  <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
</Style>

<ContentPresenter Content="This is a Test piece of text." Style="{StaticResource SampleStyle}"/>
```

Is there a way to apply this style successfully to the autogenerated `TextBlock`s short of applying it to all `TextBlock`s (e.g. declaring style as `TargetType="TextBlock"` with no `Key`)?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can do this...

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" x:Key="WrappingStyle">
            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

...then where you define your `ContentPresenter`...

```
<ContentPresenter Content="This text is going to wrap...">
            <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource WrappingStyle}"/>
            </ContentPresenter.Resources>
</ContentPresenter>
```

The `TargetType` is set since as you know the `ContentPresenter` will not always hold a `TextBlock` in it.

Answer (score 11):

If you are not using the style elsewhere, you could apply it directly to the content presenter:

```
<ContentPresenter.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
    </Style>
</ContentPresenter.Resources>
```

Comment: Very good solution, this allows the default behavior of either auto-creating a TextBox just from a string or string resource, with custom styles to the TextBox pre-defined, or allowing to define custom content if more than a simple TextBox is required.