# How can I wrap text in a label using WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, label, word-wrap

I have a **`TextBox`** and a Label. After clicking a button, I execute the following code:

```
 label1.Content = textbox1.Text;
```

My question is, how do I enable text wrapping of the label? There may be too much text to display on one line, and I want it to automatically wrap to multiple lines if that is the case.

Answer (score 454, accepted):

The `Label` control doesn't directly support text wrapping in WPF. You should use a [`TextBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.aspx) instead. (Of course, you can place the `TextBlock` *inside* of a `Label` control, if you wish.)

Sample code:

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec adipiscing
    nulla quis libero egestas lobortis. Duis blandit imperdiet ornare. Nulla
    ac arcu ut purus placerat congue. Integer pretium fermentum gravida.
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: This is fine, but not if you want to use the Target property feature of the Label--which to be fair is probably the *only* reason you'd use a Label over a TextBlock. I have provided an answer to this question that show's how to get wrapping in a Label (below)

Comment: JulianM - they already readonly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073244/making-textblock-readonly ? Maybe they weren't in 2011

Comment: @JulianM are you confusing `TextBlock` with `TextBox`? -- `TextBlock`'s have been read-only since WPF was code named "Avalon".

Comment: I needed to set `Padding="5"` to match the padding in my other `Label` controls on the form. See Rajesh's answer below.

Answer (score 119):

Often you cannot replace a `Label` with a `TextBlock` as you want to the use the `Target` property (which sets focus to the *targeted* control when using the keyboard e.g. ALT+C in the sample code below), as that's all a `Label` really offers over a `TextBlock`.

However, a `Label` uses a `TextBlock` to render text (if a string is placed in the `Content` property, which it typically is); therefore, you can add a style for `TextBlock` inside the `Label` like so:

```
<Label              
    Content="_Content Text:"
    Target="{Binding ElementName=MyTargetControl}">
    <Label.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
        </Style>
    </Label.Resources>
 </Label>
 <CheckBox x:Name = "MyTargetControl" />
```

This way you get to keep the functionality of a `Label` whilst also being able to wrap the text.

Comment: Does this actually work? From what I've seen the textblock that WPF adds does not exist in the logical tree and will not pick up your resource.

Comment: Yes, this does work—I tested it before I published my answer. You are right in that the elements targeted are not in the logical tree, but it's the visual tree that matters here.

Comment: This is a few years old but this does not seem to work with VS 2015. What does seem to work is using a TextBlock in a label

<Label>
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Whatever" />
</Label>

Answer (score 119):

I used the following code.

```
    <Label>
        <Label.Content>
            <AccessText TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="xxxxx"/>
        </Label.Content>
    </Label>
```

Comment: This is what worked best for me. Simple, no need to use other controls or add much code.

Comment: @jeremychan, I would mark this as the answer. I am happy that I scrolled down and seen this answer.

Comment: I revert my up vote.. I tried using this but it by-passed my "HorizontalAlignment="Center"". Unlike using Textblock, it didn't...

Comment: The Label.Content part is unnecessary, as anything within the label tag is automatically content. Nonetheless, an excellent answer as it retains the ability to provide access keys, where all the solutions using a TextBlock fail in this regard.

Answer (score 40):

You can put a TextBlock inside the label:

```
<Label> 
  <TextBlock Text="Long Text . . . ." TextWrapping="Wrap" /> 
</Label>
```

Comment: I like this approach because it allows your Label styles to apply to this textblock without having to make additional styles for the TextBlock.

Answer (score 20):

To wrap text in the label control, change the the template of label as follows:

```
<Style x:Key="ErrorBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFF08A73"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFE3DF"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" CornerRadius="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                     
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                </Border>
                    
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Addendum: if you need to add text wrapping or other TextBlock-specific properties you can mix-in with the following recipe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970285/wpf-4-contentpresenter-textwrapping-style-is-not-applied-to-implicitedly-generat

Comment: Be careful with this answer. A normal Label can have a control as its content but this one doesn't allow it.

Answer (score 13):

Instead of using a Label class, I would recommend using a [TextBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.aspx).  This allows you to set the [TextWrapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.textwrapping.aspx) appropriately.

You can always do:

```
 label1.Content = new TextBlock() { Text = textBox1.Text, TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap };
```

However, if all this "label" is for is to display text, use a `TextBlock` instead.

Comment: I ended up using this method for populating dynamic label contents.  Seems to be the easiest and cleanest method.  I imagine you could incorporate the line into the label1 definition, i.e.
<br/>
`Label label1 = new Label() { Content = new TextBlock() { Text = caption, TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap }, FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal };`

Answer (score 6):

We need to put some kind of control that can wrap text like textblock/textbox

```
 <Label Width="120" Height="100" >
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
            this is a very long text inside a textblock and this needs to be on multiline.
        </TextBlock>
    </Label>
```

Answer (score 2):

try use this

```
lblresult.Content = lblresult.Content + "prime are :" + j + "\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 <Label x:Name="datetimeofmsg" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4.286,55,0,0" 
           VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="{x:Null}" 
           FontWeight="Bold" Width="61.714" Height="20" Foreground="White">
        <Label.Content>
            <AccessText TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </Label.Content>
    </Label>
```

Answer (score 1):

I used this to retrieve data from MySql Database:

```
AccessText a = new AccessText();    
a.Text=reader[1].ToString();       // MySql reader
a.Width = 70;
a.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.WrapWithOverflow;
labels[i].Content = a;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try my version

```
<Label x:Name="myLabel">
        <TextBox FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent"
                 IsReadOnly="true" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Focusable="False"
                 Foreground="{Binding Foreground, ElementName=myLabel}"
            Text="longMeeeeessssagggeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee_Ooooooooeeeeeeeeeee" />
</Label>
```

Not necessary to use ScrollViewer control.

Answer (score 0):

Something else to keep in mind is parent containers, `<Grid/>` and what not. Impacted `<ColumnDefinition/>` needs to be adjusted accordingly, or the wrapping has no effect.

```xml
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <!-- auto prohibits wrapping -->
    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
    <!-- whereas the Kleene star allows wrapping -->
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```