# making textblock readonly

Tags: wpf, textblock

currently i have a textblock placed in a scroll viewer control. How do i make the textblock read only?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[Textblocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.aspx) are already readonly. They are intended to display a small amount of flow text. Perhaps you thought you were dealing with a [TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.aspx) instead?

Comment: oh ok thanks for your info. because i read from somewhere in order to make textblock text selectable i have to make the textblock read only

Comment: If that is what you want, you should use the TextBOX control (I provided a link in my answer) and set IsReadOnly="true" on that new TextBox control. That will do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

BinaryTox1n answered your question, but if you need the text to be selectable see the [previous StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136435/any-way-to-make-a-wpf-textblock-selectable).

Answer (score 0):

Bind the Textblock to a property with only a getter and it will be a readonly textblock.