# Split content onto different line

Tags: c#

I wanna split the content of a Label into smaller part. For example the sentence is "Hello how are you now. I'm fine thanks you". How do I split the sentence every time a full stop appear and I wanna make the second sentence place below the first sentence. Thank you.

Comment: What type of the application do you implement? WPF, WebForms, WinForms...?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can use `String.Split(new[] { '.', '?', '!' , StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` and format your array items like `string.Format("{0} \n{1}", array[0], array[1]);`

Answer (score 2):

To split text into senteces

```
string[] sentences = Regex.Split(input, @"(?<=[\.!\?])\s+");
```

then you can place your senteces in different boxes, or add new lines.

EDIT:
in your code:

```
var input = label1.Content;
string[] sentences = Regex.Split(input, @"(?<=[\.!\?])\s+");
```

but to allow multilines you should use textblock and write:

```
textblock1.Content = string.Join("\n", sentences);
```

[how to allow multiline in textblock](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5013100/1714342)

Comment: thank you. But the sentence I get is read from database which is label1.content = reader["Greeting"]; How should I insert the line above into my codes?

Comment: @user3016854 in your code it should look like above, but to allow multilines you should use textblock

Comment: I have tried it but the Regex.Split(input, @"(?<=[\.!\?])\s+"); has an error says "The best overloaded method match for "System.Text.RegularTextExpression.Regex.Split(string, int)" has some invalid arguments".

Comment: thanks I have solved it, I just change the var data type for "input" into string and add ToString() behind the label1.Content;

Answer (score 0):

You could also simply use [`string.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx):

```
string[] sentences = text.Split(new[] { '.', '?', '!' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string newText = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, sentences.Select(s => s.Trim()));
```