# wpf storyboard animation in button content and MessageBox

Tags: wpf, button, storyboard, messagebox

I have a strange behavior of a storyboard animation inside a Button.

I Adjusted an existing Button style already used in my program, to display an animation to notify the user for the action in progress: some new buttons activate in theirs specific click event a long time running sequence (10 seconds). I though to add the animation directly in the btnStyle.

The buttonClick event start a method in which in the first line I Set an attachedProperty of the button to start the animation and in the last line the attachedProperty is reset.

The strange behaviour is that the animation NORMALLY doesn't show: it is displayed only in the case if in the middle of the buttonClick event method there is a System.Windows.MessageBox to ask confirmation to the user.

To Debug the situation, in the code where I activated the Animation, I added the `Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait`: the mouse changes for every buttonClick event (with or without the MEssageBox).

To add tests, I separated the buttonClick event code in a specific method and i started it also with a Dispatcher.BeginInvoke.

No way at all to see the Animation.

Thanks in advance....

This is the scenario:

1) in a Windows, i have some buttons declared as follow:

```
<Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Style="{DynamicResource btnStyle}" Name="btnCashQ_Report" Content="Stampa situazione" />
```

2) in a resource file i declared the btnStyle:

```
<!-- STYLE BUTTON #START -->
<Style x:Key="btnStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border x:Name="OuterBorder"
                        CornerRadius="3" 
                        Background="{DynamicResource ButtonGradient}">
                    <Border
                            x:Name="InnerBorder"
                            CornerRadius="3"
                            Background="{DynamicResource ButtonUpGradient}"
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition  Width="12*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ContentPresenter 
                                x:Name="ContentSite" 
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                            >
                                <!-- $HELP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970285/wpf-4-contentpresenter-textwrapping-style-is-not-applied-to-implicitedly-generat -->
                                <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" >
                                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                                        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
                                        <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </ContentPresenter.Resources>
                            </ContentPresenter>

                            <local:LoadingPanelSopra_6_12
                                x:Name="Animation" 
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                AnimationEnable="{Binding Path=(buttonExt:WpfButtonExtensionsMethods.AnimationEnabled), RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                            />
                        </Grid>

                    </Border>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="InnerBorder" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource ButtonDownGradient}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="InnerBorder" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource ButtonDisabledGradient}"  />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Silver"  />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="SlateGray"  />
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
                    </Trigger>

                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="buttonExt:WpfButtonExtensionsMethods.AnimationEnabled" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="MidnightBlue" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe Black" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16px" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,5,5,5" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="25" />
    <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="50" />
    <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="250" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
</Style>
```

In the `btnStyle`, you may find that the button contains a `Grid` to arrange both the `ContentPresenter` to arrange the TextBox Caption and a `LoadingPanelSopra_6_12`: this last is a my custom UserControl which draw an arc with small square blocks using a StoryBoard Animation.

The animation is turned on by the attached property:

```
AnimationEnable="{Binding Path=(buttonExt:WpfButtonExtensionsMethods.AnimationEnabled), RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
```

Here following, the usercontrol xaml (i cut the repeated SplineColorKeyFrame tags)

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="Svdh.SmStation.AutoCash.Biz.LoadingPanelSopra_6_12"

    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ctrls="clr-namespace:Svdh.Controls.WPF;assembly=Svdh.Controls.WPF"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Svdh.SmStation.AutoCash.Biz;assembly="
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"         
    xmlns:svdhAuto="clr-namespace:Svdh.Automation.Config;assembly=Svdh.Automation.Config"


        mc:Ignorable="d"
        d:Height="16" 
        d:Width="16" >

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Svdh.SmStation.AutoCash.Biz;Component/Resources/StylesThemeFree.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Svdh.SmStation.AutoCash.Biz;component/Resources/Skin_Classic_Blue.xaml"  />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Svdh.SmStation.AutoCash.Biz;component/Resources/Skin_HighContrast_Yellow.xaml"  />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <!-- ottimizzazione $HELP: http://mrpfister.com/journal/improving-wpf-rendering-performance/ -->
            <Storyboard x:Key="ProgressAnimation_6_12" Completed="onStoryBoardCompleted" Timeline.DesiredFrameRate="5" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="LowQuality">
                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="block12" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.OpacityMask).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="#AA000000"/>
                    and so on....
                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="block11" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.OpacityMask).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                    and so on....
                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:03.9000000" Value="#AA000000"/>
                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="block10" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.OpacityMask).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                    and so on....
                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:03.9000000" Value="#9B000000"/>
                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="block9" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.OpacityMask).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                    and so on....
                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:03.9000000" Value="#91000000"/>
                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="block8" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.OpacityMask).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:03.9000000" Value="#7F000000"/>
                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="block7" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.OpacityMask).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:03.9000000" Value="#72000000"/>
                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="block6" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.OpacityMask).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:03.9000000" Value="#63000000"/>
                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

            </Storyboard>
        </ResourceDictionary>

    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot" Height="32" Width="88">
        <Grid Width="10.734" Height="10.004" Canvas.Left="38.614" Canvas.Top="0.331">
            <local:Block x:Name="block6" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,4.3689" OpacityMask="#64000000" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="10.004">
                <local:Block.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform/>
                        <SkewTransform/>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="-59.999999999999993"/>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </local:Block.RenderTransform>
            </local:Block>
            <local:Block x:Name="block7" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,4.3689" OpacityMask="#72000000" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="10.004">
                <local:Block.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.99999999999999989" ScaleY="0.99999999999999989"/>
                        <SkewTransform/>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="-40"/>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </local:Block.RenderTransform>
            </local:Block>
            <local:Block x:Name="block8" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,4.3689" OpacityMask="#80000000" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="10.004">
                <local:Block.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform/>
                        <SkewTransform/>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="-19.999999999999996"/>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </local:Block.RenderTransform>
            </local:Block>
            <local:Block x:Name="block9" OpacityMask="#8E000000" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,4.3689" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="10.004"/>
            <local:Block x:Name="block10" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,4.3689" OpacityMask="#9C000000" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="10.004">
                <local:Block.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform/>
                        <SkewTransform/>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="19.999999999999996"/>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </local:Block.RenderTransform>
            </local:Block>
            <local:Block x:Name="block11" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,4.3689" OpacityMask="#AA000000" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="10.004">
                <local:Block.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.99999999999999989" ScaleY="0.99999999999999989"/>
                        <SkewTransform/>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="40"/>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </local:Block.RenderTransform>
            </local:Block>
            <local:Block x:Name="block12" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,4.3689" OpacityMask="#B8000000" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="10.004">
                <local:Block.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform/>
                        <SkewTransform/>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="59.999999999999993"/>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </local:Block.RenderTransform>
            </local:Block>
        </Grid>
    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

To complete the scenario, here the code behind of the usercontrol in which I activate the storyboard animation via the AttachedProperty `AnimationEnabled`

```
Public Shared ReadOnly AnimationEnableProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("AnimationEnable",
                                                                                            GetType(Boolean),
                                                                                            GetType(LoadingPanelSopra_6_12),
                                                                                            New PropertyMetadata(False, AddressOf OnDependencyPropertyChanged))
Public Property AnimationEnable As Boolean
    Get
        Return CBool(Me.GetValue(AnimationEnableProperty))
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        Const METHOD_NAME As String = "AnimationEnable.SET()"
        Try
            Me.SetValue(AnimationEnableProperty, value)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Svdh.Dbg.IgnoreFirstChance(ex, Me, "{0}.ERL_{1}: ingored", METHOD_NAME, Erl.ToString)
        End Try
    End Set
End Property
```

which call the

```
Private Shared Sub OnDependencyPropertyChanged(d As DependencyObject, e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    Dim tbh As LoadingPanelSopra_6_12 = TryCast(d, LoadingPanelSopra_6_12)

    Select Case e.Property.Name
        Case "AnimationEnable"
            tbh.AnimationEnable_Local = CBool(e.NewValue)
    End Select
End Sub
```

who effectively triggers the interesting code

```
Private WriteOnly Property AnimationEnable_Local As Boolean
            Set(value As Boolean)
                If (value) Then
                    Me.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Visible
                    Me.IsEnabled = True
                    Me.StartAnimation()
                Else
                    Me.IsEnabled = True
                    Me.StopAnimation()
                    Me.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Hidden                           
End If
                End Set
            End Property
```

The last step in the sequence is doing by the following

```
Private Sub StartAnimation()
        Dim SB As Storyboard = DirectCast(FindResource("ProgressAnimation_6_12"), Storyboard)
        SB.Stop()
        Mouse.OverrideCursor = Nothing

        SB.Begin()
        Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait
End Sub

Private Sub StopAnimation()
        Dim SB As Storyboard = DirectCast(FindResource("ProgressAnimation_6_12"), Storyboard)

        SB.Stop()
        Mouse.OverrideCursor = Nothing
End Sub
Private Sub onStoryBoardCompleted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim SB As Storyboard = DirectCast(FindResource("ProgressAnimation_6_12"), Storyboard)
        If Me.AnimationEnable <> True Then

            SB.Stop()
            Mouse.OverrideCursor = Nothing

        Else
            SB.Begin()
            Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait

        End If
End Sub
```

As I told in the preface, `Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait` and relative `Mouse.OverrideCursor = Nothing` have effect (the mouse is displayed correctly) but the corresponding `SB.Begin()` and `SB.Stop()` really operates only if a System.Windows.MessageBox is shown in the middle of the buttonClick event method.

Thank you.