WPF Custom Label
I have created a custom style for Labels in my application, this works fine and I apply a Template to achieve the other set styles that I need, again this works fine.

STYLE DEFINITIONS:

<Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">

  <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource BackgroundBrush}" />
  <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Arrow" />
  <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{DynamicResource Font_Regular}" />
  <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{DynamicResource 400}" />
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource ForegroundBrush}" />
  <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
  <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource Label.Default}" />
  <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
  <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />

</Style>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="Label.Default" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
  
  <TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource Label.TextBlock}"
             HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}"
             Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
             VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}" />

</ControlTemplate>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="Label.ItemHeading.Emphasis.Highlight" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">

    <TextBlock x:Name="lblContent"
               FontWeight="{DynamicResource 500}"
               Foreground="{DynamicResource HighlightBrush}"
               HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}"
               Style="{DynamicResource Label.TextBlock}"
               Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />

</ControlTemplate>

<Style x:Key="Label.TextBlock" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">

  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
  <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{DynamicResource Inter}" />
  <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{DynamicResource Font_Regular}" />
  <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{DynamicResource 400}" />
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource ForegroundBrush}" />
  <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />
  <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
  <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />

</Style>


USAGE:

<Label Content="{Binding Reseller}"
       ContentStringFormat="Powered by {0}"
       Grid.Column="1"
       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
       Template="{DynamicResource Label.ItemHeading.Emphasis.Highlight}"
       VerticalAlignment="Center"
       x:Name="lblPoweredBy" />

I have now hit one short coming of this control and it relates to my Label having a ContentStringFormat value:
EXPECTED:
Label (lblPoweredBy) should output "Powered by MyCompany", but instead it just outputs "MyCompany"
I tried adding StringFormat {TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat} to the Text property of the TextBlock, but at runtime it says this is incompatible. Can anyone help out?

You should keep a ContentPresenter in the ControlTemplates, or not set the Template property at all. ContentPresenter uses the ContentStringFormat property. You could set all the text-related properties by means of attached property setters like <Setter Property="TextElement.FontSize" Value="24"/>

Issue I have with that approach is that I have a number of Templates which I am using this sets a variety of FontSizes, Weights and Foreground colors to the label depending on the Template used

Ah, I think I misunderstood, you mean use a ContentPresenter rather than a TextBlock right? This also provides an issue as the reason for using a TextBlock was to allow the content to wrap (if needed)

https://stackoverflow.com/q/3970285/1136211

This Label is totally redundant, isn't it? Instead of wrapping a TextBlock into a Label, why don't you use the TextBlock directly?

The Label.ContetStringFormat is applied to the Label.Content value. This value is never rendered so there is nothing for the Label to format. You have replaced the content with a TextBlock. The ContentControl.ContentStringFormat is only applied when the ContentControl has no template. In this case the ContentPresenter of the ContentControl will create a TexBlock and assign the formatted text to it and then add the TextBlock to its ContentPresenter.Content.

It's in general not recommended to use a ContentControl (or Label) to bind to strings. This will cause a new copy of the string each time the binding updates. TextBlock manages to avoid this costs.
